# Hide url in subdirectory install?

Tags: 7, .htaccess

in my site I use version 7 of Drupal and Linux OS on the server, and need to hide the subdirectory of the installation when access by LINK ...
explaining better:
Current link: www.site.com/folder
I want to change for only:
www.site.com
I searched in various forums, websites and how is an old subject, I believe that there was a change in the code to hide / delete the symbolic url paste ...
In the folder / root .htaccess I created left like this:

`Options + FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Folder / $ 1 [L]`

Thus, to access the site, only the index remains without the folder ... I want the whole site be without referencing the subfolder where it was installed ... How do I do this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this rewrite rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Change `subfolder` and `www.example.com`.

Also, you can try with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Again change you domain and subfolder name.

Comment: This dont work... i try in too many ways and not work, just the first access from link appears without a subfolder....

Comment: mixerowsky, This actually worked for me, except, all of my links are still including the subfolder. How do I gave ALL links to string out the subfolder?
I should also say that I can nav to the links without the "subfolder" part, but naturally I want that part gone/hidden.